# Unable to access IIS Windows Server 2008 through a Mac

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac-osx, iis-7

Basically I have a computer running windows server 2008 and have set up a DNS server, active directory, and IIS to test my applications. I have a Mac as another computer and it has Windows 7 and Mac OSX on it.

If I am on the Windows 7 side, I am able to remotely access the windows server, access my SVN server on the server, and view my IIS applications through the browsers.

But if I am on the mac side, I am unable to do any of that and I don't know why the Mac side can't even find the server.

The server is inside a network so it should be visible over the network shouldn't it?

I don't know what the problem could be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Start with basic connectivity test - ping. Than check the DNS configured on the MAC, based on what you say it should point to Windows 2008 AD server.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Mac correctly resolve the hostname of the server?

Open a Terminal window and type "ping " followed by

Do you get something that looks like:

"PING  (): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from : icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.909 ms"

Or do you get:

"ping: cannot resolve : Unknown host"

Try ping again with the domain appended to the server's name:

"ping ."

Is the Mac bound to Active Directory?